# Why has connection to my minecraft server (via nginx) been lost after setting up new network, while all other nginx served services work fine?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, minecraft

I host a bunch of services (via subdomains) in nginx, e.g. mine.mydomain.com, doku.mydomain.com, etc. This has run smoothly for years (Ubuntu Server, now on 20.04 LTS, almost everything, including nginx itself running in Docker). But after setting up a new network (new hardware, segregate stuff in VLANs), the kids minecraft server is not accessible via the subdomain/domain (mine.mydomain.com), though all other services I have tested are still working fine.

I did a port forward of port 25565 (minecraft) to see if I could access using my externalIP:port, bypassing nginx. This works fine. What is weird is, now I could also access the minecraft server **though my external mine.mydomain.com**. I don't see how that's even relevant, since I forward ports 80, 443 for nginx, and that should be what's needed (it was on my old setup). But it's consistent, as soon as I remove the port forward, the access (via nginx, mine.mydomain.com) is gone, and I get the error:

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnecttException: Connection refused:
```

I have separated a lot of the nginx config, but the different files are below. First is the minecraft-specific one, then one for a dokuwiki instance (that works fine) for comparison, as well as the ssl, nginx, proxy confs.

**minecraft**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name mine.mydomain.com;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
#       auth_basic "Restricted";
#       auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://10.0.30.21:25565;
    }
}
```

**dokuwiki**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name doku.mydomain.com;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
#       auth_basic "Restricted";
#       auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://10.0.30.21:8844;
    }
}
```

**default**
(I have `other_domain.com` because I host stuff on two different domains. But `other_domain.com` is only a website, all other services are on the mydomain.com domain, with subdomains for each service, like the two examples above).

```
## Version 2021/01/03 - Changelog: https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-swag/commits/master/root/defaults/default

error_page 502 /502.html;

# redirect all traffic to https
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# main server block
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    root /config/www;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name other_domain.com; ### ADD AFTER UPDATE!

    # enable subfolder method reverse proxy confs
    include /config/nginx/proxy-confs/*.subfolder.conf;

    # all ssl related config moved to ssl.conf
    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    # enable for ldap auth
    #include /config/nginx/ldap.conf;

    # enable for Authelia
    #include /config/nginx/authelia-server.conf;

    # enable for geo blocking
    # See /config/nginx/geoip2.conf for more information.
    #if ($allowed_country = no) {
    #return 444;
    #}

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$args =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass 10.0.30.21:9000; ### ADD AFTER UPDATE!
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

# sample reverse proxy config for password protected couchpotato running at IP 192.168.1.50 port 5050 with base url "cp"
# notice this is within the same server block as the base
# don't forget to generate the .htpasswd file as described on docker hub
#   location ^~ /cp {
#       auth_basic "Restricted";
#       auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;
#       include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
#       proxy_pass http://192.168.1.50:5050/cp;
#   }

}

# sample reverse proxy config without url base, but as a subdomain "cp", ip and port same as above
# notice this is a new server block, you need a new server block for each subdomain
#server {
#   listen 443 ssl http2;
#   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
#
#   root /config/www;
#   index index.html index.htm index.php;
#
#   server_name cp.*;
#
#   include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;
#
#   client_max_body_size 0;
#
#   location / {
#       auth_basic "Restricted";
#       auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;
#       include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
#       proxy_pass http://192.168.1.50:5050;
#   }
#}

# sample reverse proxy config for "heimdall" via subdomain, with ldap authentication
# ldap-auth container has to be running and the /config/nginx/ldap.conf file should be filled with ldap info
# notice this is a new server block, you need a new server block for each subdomain
#server {
#   listen 443 ssl http2;
#   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
#
#   root /config/www;
#   index index.html index.htm index.php;
#
#   server_name heimdall.*;
#
#   include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;
#
#   include /config/nginx/ldap.conf;
#
#   client_max_body_size 0;
#
#   location / {
#       # the next two lines will enable ldap auth along with the included ldap.conf in the server block
#       auth_request /auth;
#       error_page 401 =200 /ldaplogin;
#
#       include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
#       resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
#       set $upstream_app heimdall;
#       set $upstream_port 443;
#       set $upstream_proto https;
#       proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;
#   }
#}

# sample reverse proxy config for "heimdall" via subdomain, with Authelia
# Authelia container has to be running in the same user defined bridge network, with container name "authelia", and with 'path: "authelia"' set in its configuration.yml
# notice this is a new server block, you need a new server block for each subdomain
#server {
#   listen 443 ssl http2;
#   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
#
#   root /config/www;
#   index index.html index.htm index.php;
#
#   server_name heimdall.*;
#
#   include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;
#
#   include /config/nginx/authelia-server.conf;
#
#   client_max_body_size 0;
#
#   location / {
#       # the next line will enable Authelia along with the included authelia-server.conf in the server block
#       include /config/nginx/authelia-location.conf;
#
#       include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
#       resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
#       set $upstream_app heimdall;
#       set $upstream_port 443;
#       set $upstream_proto https;
#       proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;
#   }
#}

# enable subdomain method reverse proxy confs
include /config/nginx/proxy-confs/*.subdomain.conf;
# enable proxy cache for auth
proxy_cache_path cache/ keys_zone=auth_cache:10m;
```

**ssl.conf**

```
# session settings
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

# Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE cipher suites
ssl_dhparam /config/nginx/dhparams.pem;

# ssl certs
ssl_certificate /config/keys/letsencrypt/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /config/keys/letsencrypt/privkey.pem;

# protocols
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers REDACTED;

# HSTS, remove # from the line below to enable HSTS
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;


# OCSP Stapling
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

# Optional additional headers
#add_header Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests";
#add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
#add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
#add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
#add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge" always;
#add_header Cache-Control "no-transform" always;
#add_header Referrer-Policy "same-origin" always;
```

**proxy.conf**

```
client_max_body_size 10m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;

#Timeout if the real server is dead
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

# Advanced Proxy Config
send_timeout 5m;
proxy_read_timeout 240;
proxy_send_timeout 240;
proxy_connect_timeout 240;

# Basic Proxy Config
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
proxy_redirect  http://  $scheme://;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
#proxy_cookie_path / "/; HTTPOnly; Secure"; # enable at your own risk, may break certain apps
proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_session;
proxy_no_cache $cookie_session;
proxy_buffers 32 4k;
```

**nginx.con**

```
user abc;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /config/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /config/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /config/nginx/site-confs/*;
  
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
daemon off;
```

**docker-compose.yaml** file; minecraft and nginx parts (nginx is aprt of the "swag" container):

```
  swag:
    image: linuxserver/swag
    container_name: swag
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/docker/letsencrypt/config:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    ports:
      - "10.0.30.21:80:80"
      - "10.0.30.21:443:443"
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1004
      - EMAIL=READCTED
      - TZ=REDACTED
      - URL=mydomain.com
      - SUBDOMAINS=hass,dash,mqtt,enter,doku,print,mail,panel,mine,rcon,next,hassos 
      - DHLEVEL=4096
      - VALIDATION=http
      - EXTRA_DOMAINS=other_domain.com
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.11.0.2

  minecraft_server:
    image: itzg/minecraft-server:latest
    container_name: minecraft_server
    ports:
      - "10.0.30.21:25565:25565"
    volumes:
      - "/mnt/data/docker/minecraft:/data"
    environment:
      EULA: "TRUE"
      ENABLE_RCON: "TRUE"
      RCON_PASSWORD: "REDACTED"
      RCON_PORT: 28016
      CONSOLE: 'FALSE'
    restart: always
```

Comment: You do realize Minecraft does not use HTTP, right? Nginx can also work as a TCP proxy. But why bother?

Comment: I actually did not know that (didn't look much into minecraft, just tried quickly adding a Docker container for the kids and it worked on old setup). Does that explain why I can access it via HTTP when I forward port 25565 now, but I didn't have to port forward before putting the server on a VLAN (I honestly don't know)?